# Why are there finitely many ramified prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Reference: Neukirch - ANT p.49

Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain with the quotient field $K$ and $L/K$ be a finite separable field extension and $A$ be the integral closure of $R$ in $L$.

Let $\theta\in A$ such that $L=K(\theta)$ and define $J:=\{\alpha\in A: \alpha A\subset R[\theta]\}$ and $m$ be the minimal polynomial for $\theta$ over $K$.

Let $d$ be the discriminant of the polynomial $m$, so that $d=\prod_{0\leq i<j\leq n-1} (\theta^i -\theta^j)$ where $n=[L:K]$.

The text shows that any prime ideal satisfying $d\notin P$ and $PA+J=A$ is unramified in $L$.

How do I conclude that there are only finitely many ramified prime ideals in $L$? That is, how do I prove that there are finitely many prime ideals satisfying $d\in P$ or $PA+J\neq A$?

Since $R$ is a Dedekind domain, of course, there are finitely many prime ideals satisfying $d\in P$. However, why are there finitely many prime ideals $P$ such that $PA+J\neq A$?

Comment: What does it mean to be ramified for a prime ideal?

Comment: @Ninja A prime $P$ is unramified if and only if the ramification of $Q$ is $1$ and the extension $(A/Q)/(R/P)$ is seperable for every prime ideal $Q$ which divides $PA$. And any prime which is not unramified is said to be ramified.

Comment: Can you show that if $PA$ and $J$ are relatively prime, then $PA + J = A$?

Comment: Yes those are equivalent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit unsure of where you're stuck, since I think one can show that the set of primes $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $\mathfrak{p}A + \mathfrak{F} \neq A$ is finite in much the same way that one shows the set of primes such that $d \in \mathfrak{p}$ is finite.

Since you didn't state this explicitly, let me first note that $A$ is also a Dedekind domain: its Krull dimension is $1$ by the [Cohen-Seidenberg theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Going_up_and_going_down), it is integrally closed, and one can use Proposition 5.17 of Atiyah-Macdonald to show that it is Noetherian.

Since $R$ is Dedekind, then $dR$ has a unique prime factorization
$$
dR = \mathfrak{p}_1^{e_1} \cdots \mathfrak{p}_s^{e_s} \, .
$$
Since to contain is to divide, then the only prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ such that $d \in \mathfrak{p}$ are the primes $\mathfrak{p}_1, \ldots, \mathfrak{p}_s$ appearing in the factorization of $dR$.

Similarly since $A$ is Dedekind, then $\mathfrak{F}$ has a unique prime factorization
$$
\mathfrak{F} = \mathfrak{P}_1^{a_1} \cdots \mathfrak{P}_t^{a_t} \, .
$$
If $\mathfrak{p}$ is an ideal of $R$ such that $\mathfrak{p}A + \mathfrak{F} \neq A$, then 
there exists a prime $\mathfrak{P}$ of $A$ such that $\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{p}A$ and $\mathfrak{P} \mid \mathfrak{F}$.  Then $\mathfrak{P} = \mathfrak{P}_i$ for some $i$ by the uniqueness of factorization of ideals.  Thus we see that an ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$ satisfies $\mathfrak{p}A + \mathfrak{F} \neq A$ iff $\mathfrak{p} = \mathfrak{P_i} \cap A$ for some $i$, i.e., for one of the primes appearing in the factorization of $\mathfrak{F}$.

Answer (score 1):

More of an extended comment than an answer:

Ramification of primes in number theory is basically the same picture as ramification which occurs in  the theory of branched covering spaces (for example, see [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469112/intuition-in-studying-splitting-and-ramification-of-prime-ideals/1469184#1469184)).

The basic philosophy is: prime ideals are points. For an integral domain, its "dimension" (ie, Krull dimension) is the longest chain of prime ideals you can find, minus 1. For rings of integers, $(0)$ is prime, and every nonzero prime is maximal, so the longest chain you can find is 2, so the dimension is 1. Under this philosophy, the prime ideal $(0)$ should be thought of as a "generic point", which is a point whose closure (in the Zariski topology) is the whole space - it is also called a codimension 0 point. The nonzero primes are then codimension 1 points (in this case, they are closed points).

It turns out that in nice situations (which includes the case of rings of integers), [ramification is a closed property which happens purely in codimension 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purity_(algebraic_geometry)). However, in the Zariski topology on an 1-dimensional integral domain, the open sets are the cofinite sets - ie, the closed sets are the finite sets, and hence ramification can only happen at closed points (ie, nonzero primes), and only had finitely many of them.